# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to copy report to file

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

We are trying to implement SonarQube 5.2 in AIX 7.1 server with Runner 2.4. We could able to install, run the runner and analyze the Java code. But we stuck with last point with error Fail to Copy the reports to the file

```
2016.09.22 01:01:54 ERROR web[o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://localhost:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=dev&projectName=ruw_model java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to copy report to file: /apps/websphere/sonar/sonarqube-5.3/data/ce/reports/AVdRITpfnSb8YuTUE-9u.zip
at org.sonar.server.computation.queue.report.ReportFiles.save(ReportFiles.java:54) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.queue.report.ReportSubmitter.submit(ReportSubmitter.java:74) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.computation.ws.SubmitAction.handle(SubmitAction.java:86) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:85) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0]
...

Caused by: java.io.IOException: not opened for reading 
    at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.checkReadable(ChannelStream.‌​java:134) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.10.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.bufferedRead(ChannelStream.j‌​ava:994) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.10.jar:na] 
    at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.access$300(ChannelStream.jav‌​a:62) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.10.jar:na] 
    at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream$InputStreamAdapter.read(Chan‌​nelStream.java:1570) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.10.jar:na] 
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:113) ~[na:1.7.0]
```

Comment: is that the end of the stacktrace, or is there a "Caused by"?

Comment: That's the end of the stacktrace Caused by: java.io.IOException: not opened for reading
 at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.checkReadable(ChannelStream.java:134) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.10.jar:na]
 at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.bufferedRead(ChannelStream.java:994) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.10.jar:na]
 at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream.access$300(ChannelStream.java:62) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.10.jar:na]
 at org.jruby.util.io.ChannelStream$InputStreamAdapter.read(ChannelStream.java:1570) ~[jruby-complete-1.7.10.jar:na]
 at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:113) ~[na:1.7.0]